# Case subquery based on date logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm taking this data and inserting it into another table as part of a conversion process. Unfortunately I'm not able to modify the table schema in either my source or target location.

I have the following source data: (Obviously just a small snapshot of the data)

```
Id  StudentID   Score   Createdate
1   1           86      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
2   1           89      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
3   1           76      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
4   1           91      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
5   1           87      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
6   1           78      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
7   1           88      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
8   2           78      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
9   2           82      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
10  2           83      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
```

My end result target data should look like this:

```
Id  StudentID   TestType    Score   Createdate
1   1           Pretest     86      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
2   1           Pretest     89      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
3   1           Pretest     76      2015-09-15 12:59:46.000
4   1           Posttest    91      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
5   1           Posttest    87      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
6   1           Posttest    78      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
7   1           Posttest    88      2015-10-14 13:45:33.000
8   2           Pretest     78      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
9   2           Pretest     82      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
10  2           Pretest     83      2014-10-23 09:21:17.000
```

Essentially the logic that occurs is that for a given student, the earliest createdate of each data record is considered to be a pretest. For that same student, any and all subsequent records on the same createdate are also pretests. For any records for the same student with a later createdate, they are all considered to be posttest.

I'm going to be probably using a case statement within an insert statement, as I have additional data elements outside of this that are also coming across for the conversion.

For simplicity sake, my script looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO targettable
(id,
studentid,
testtype,
score,
createdate)
SELECT DISTINCT
id          = sourcetable.id,
studentid   = sourcetable.studentid,
testtype    = CASE
                WHEN ????
              END
score       = sourcetable.score,
createdate  = sourcetable.createdate
FROM sourcetable
```

My question is, I'm not really sure how to handle the logic to determine the pretest/posttest testtype based on the createdate.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `dense_rank()` or `rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when dense_rank() over (partition by studentId
                                     order by cast(createdate as date)
                                    ) = 1
             then 'Pretest'
             else 'Posttest'
        end) as TestType
from sourcetable t;
```

Comment: Wow. That was incredibly easy and super powerful. Thank you so much for that!!